# Thymeleaf desplegable MVC

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

Estoy con un proyecto basico de una agenda telefonica con una serie de datos en el que hay una serie de requisitios.

Spring boot

Thymeleaf

mySql

jpa

El proyecto esta avanzado pero me encuentro el siguiente problema, los usuarios deben tener una provincia desde una tabla de la base de datos diferente a la del contacto (para poder modificarse en el futuro). Mi solucion ha consistido en agregar un desplegable con las provincias y añadir ese "Dato" a nuestra bbdd creando un atributo provinciacontacto.

he intentado hacer esto:

```
<select >
<option th:each="provincia : ${provincias}" th:value="${provincia.idprovincia}" th:text="${provincia.provincia}"
th:selected="${provincia.provincia == contactos.provinciacontacto}"></option>
</select>
```

Con esto pretendo asignar el nombre de la provincia que ha seleccionado al campo provinciacontacto perteneciente a la tabla contacto.
Pero no consigo hacer que funcione

todo lo demas funciona, me crea un desplegable con las provincias , lista contactos edita borra etc pero esto me trae de cabeza.